# Network graph from github

Tags: git, github

I am new to the git, and started a simple project, just to learn about branches and commits.
My problem is with the github network graph tool.

Here is the log:

- Initial commit to main
- Other commit adding stuff to the main branch
- Creating a second branch (layout-creation)
- Commited stuff to that branch
- Pushed to the remote using `git push --set-upstream origin layout-creation`

After that, my new goal was to merge the main branch with the layout-creation branch. For that, I used these command lines:

- git checkout main
- git merge layout-creation
- git push origin main

I expected the graph to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AiXq.png)

but it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH69Z.png)

What do I have to do in order to achieve the first graph (with command lines)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did what's called a *fast-forward merge*.  When you do `git merge` and one branch is a superset of the other, by default, Git just updates the branch you're merging into to be exactly the same as the other branch.

If you want to create a merge commit in such a case, then you want to add the `--no-ff` option to do so.  That will result in a merge commit, which will give the graph the expected shape.