# why git merge operation is not showing in git log?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, git-branch

I'm new to git. I've done some simple operations:

create a repo
add an file 'A' into the local repo, then stage, commit and push to the master branch (commit1)

create a branch by running `git checkout -b branch_name`

create a new file 'B' and edit 'A', stage, commit, then `git push origin branch_name` (commit2)

 then to merge it to master branch, I simply run `git checkout master`, `git merge branch_name`,`git push origin master`.

 Remote master branch has updated. Then I run `git log` in master branch, only 2 commits are shown:

commit1 ae6ebbb... (HEAD -> master, origin/branch_name, origin/master, branch_name)

commit2 ccc6af3...

How Can I find the merge history? (tried git log --merges doesn't work) Am I making any mistake in this process? The reason I want to get the merge hash is to revert back to the status before merge. Could plz any one tell me how to do it?

Comment: Fast-forward merge. See the answer in this neighbour question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66309133/7976758

Comment: Git default merge strategy is **Fast-forward if possible**. If you wanna see the merge commit, you should add the `--no-ff` parameter